# Why twice the output in the console from code for a maximum (same code for minimum normal)?

Tags: powershell, max, min

The execution of the following code gives twice the result for that part of it that concerns the maximum but only once for that part meant to produce the minimum, as it should; the only difference is the change of `-le` into `-ge` to pass from the code for the minimum to that of the maximum. Here is that code;

```
$SS1=(ls $home\Documents\Doo).creationtime.Ticks
foreach($x in $SS1){$SS1=$SS1|where-object{$_ -ge $x}};$SS1
$SS=(ls $home\Documents\Doo).creationtime.Ticks
foreach($x in $SS){$SS=$SS|where-object{$_ -le $x}};$SS
```

Here is the output;

```
636940445900142078
636940445900142078
636940445887555535
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Use `set-strictmode` and double-check variable names. `$SS` and `$SS1` are easy to mistype.

Comment: Can you not use `Sort` and `Select` to get the values you want? `$max = $SS1 | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -First 1` and `$min = $SS1 | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object` to achieve the desired effect.

```
$SS1=(ls $home\Documents\Doo).creationtime.Ticks
$min,$max = $SS1 | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 1 -Last 1
```

`$min` will now hold the lowest ticks value. `$max` will now hold the highest ticks value.